# Predestroy not called when application deployed

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am trying close Kafka connection for consumer app sping boot base
I perform this in method marked @predestroy as following :

```
@Component
public abstract class KafkaMessageHandler<T extends MessageLite> implements MessageBrokerHandler<T> {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    @Qualifier("Kafka")
    private MessageBrokerFactory<T> messageBrokerFactory;
    private MessageBrokerConsumer messageBrokerConsumer;

    protected String getKafkaTopicNamePrefix() {
        return kafkaTopicNamePrefix;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() 
        //some init code 
    }

    @PreDestroy 
    private void close() {  //---------> the method not called after several deployments  
        logger.info("KafkaMessageHandler close called");
        messageBrokerConsumer.stop(); //calls Kafka consumer close
    }
}
```

As expected , the close method called when accessing /actuator/shutdown
But when applicatioin re-deployed in Kubernetes , this code not always called
Is there need some special handling  for kubernetes redeployment ?
Thanks

Comment: you can try by adding preStop hook or increase terminationGracePeriodSeconds in kubernetes. check this: https://muralitechblog.com/kubernetes-graceful-shutdown-of-pods/